# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener gives "Could not establish connection"-error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to make Chrome-extensions (manifest v3) and I'm trying to understand how "addListener" works, more specifically "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener".

One thing I don't understand is why Chrome throws this error at me all the time:

*Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
*

I feel that I'm missing something very important on how messages work between backgrounds.js and content.js. Any suggestions?

In `backgrounds.js` I have this code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener ( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.status === 'complete' && tab.url) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { type: "RELOADED" });
    
  }
});
```

And in my `content.js` I have this code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.type === "RELOADED") {

    let prismicUrl = document.location.href;
    
    const prismicUrlMustExist = /~b/; // Normal
    const prismicUrlMustExist2 = /&b=/; // Efter sökning
    const articleUrlMustExist = /--ec/;
   
    if (prismicUrlMustExist.test(prismicUrl) || prismicUrlMustExist2.test(prismicUrl)) {
      console.info("Hittade artikel. Väntar en sekund.");
      setTimeout(() => {  initiate(); }, 1000);
      console.info("Försöker hitta sidebar.");
    } else if (articleUrlMustExist.test(prismicUrl)) {
      console.info("Hittaden artikel på sajten.");
      setTimeout(() => {  initiate_article(); }, 1000);
    } else {
      console.warn("Error: hittade ingen kompatibel sida.");
    }
  }
});
```

And `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Links in Prismic",
  "action": {},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.7.5",
  "description": "Adds useful functions to Prismic when working with articles and products.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "icons": { "16": "/images/icon16.png",
             "48": "/images/icon48.png",
             "128": "/images/icon128.png" },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://prisjakt.prismic.io/*",
        "https://www.prisjakt.nu/*",
        "https://www.prisjakt.no/*",
        "https://www.prisjagt.dk/*",
        "https://hintaopas.fi/*",
        "https://ledenicheur.fr/*",
        "https://pricespy.co.uk/*",
        "https://pricespy.co.nz/*"
       
      ]
    }
  ]
  
}
```

Feel free to highlight any improvements I can make to do this in a more effective way, or tell if you need more information about the code.

Comment: Please post your manifest.json

Comment: Apologies, I have added it. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: onUpdated is fired for all tabs including those where your content_scripts doesn't match. You need to add a condition for the URL or simply suppress the error by adding `()=>chrome.runtime.lastError` callback to sendMessage or `.catch(()=>{})` afterwards. However, I don't see the need for onUpdated as your content script will automatically run inside the tab when it's reloaded.

Comment: Thank you for the answer wOxxOm. I used your last solution ".catch(()=>{})" for now but will read more on how it works for a better solution. 
I actually don't get it to work for every reload without onUpdated. I simply does not load at all.